# In Backbone how do I trigger a method every time I execute an Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, authentication, backbone.js

So, every time I have an AJAX call in my Backbone app, I want to hit a method which essentially goes off the the server and checks if I'm authenticated using a JWT token. This token has an expiry time, so let's say that the expiry time is 1 minute for sake of argument. If I stay on that page and upload a file after 30 seconds, all is well. If I upload a file 2 minutes later, it should check if I'm authenticated, see that I'm not, and boot me back to the login page.

Now, of course I could add this call to the method in every one of my AJAX calls like so (I wouldn't do it in an if like below, but this is just to illustrate my point...)

```
if (isAuthenticated === true) {

            $.ajax({
                url: '/dosomething',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                processData: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false
            }).done(function () {

                //do stuff here
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
            });

}
```

The problem is is that I have a lot of AJAX calls, so it feels like I'm wasting time by adding this method call to every AJAX call. I'm not too familiar with all of Backbone's ins and outs, so I just wondered if there was something I could do to bind my method to ALL AJAX calls?

Cheers!

Comment: `$.ajax` is jquery not backbone

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fire certain action before and after every ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898381/how-to-fire-certain-action-before-and-after-every-ajax-call)

Comment: BTW backbone could do this [but you have to call it slightly differently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980586/how-to-get-backbone-ajax-to-return-data-on-success)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ajaxSend? https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr) {
    if (isAuthenticated === false){
        xhr.abort();
    }
});
```